# Table View inside of View Controller

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

All,

I have a regular view controller with several buttons on it, but when one of the buttons is pressed it retrieves information that I want to throw right above the buttons.

For the sake of this, imagine a blank view controller with one button at the bottom. When this button is called, it gets X number of items that need to be listed (and available for selection) right above the button.

I tried illustrating it for you here. :X lol. There are three items viewed, but say that 10 items came back - I need to be able to scroll through the list as well.

The question is this: how do I add a scrolling view (possibly table view) inside of my view controller so that this works as explained?

```
__________________
|                |
|                |
|     item 1     |
|                |
|     item 2     |
|                |
|     item 3     |
|                |
|                |
|    (button)    |
|                |
|________________|
```

Thanks

Comment: You're not asking anything. Your just telling us how your application works/is supposed to work. What's your problem?

Comment: @Erik: Oops, that's embarrassing! I just added the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply add the `UITableView` as a subview of the view controller and implement the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols as usual.

It's not harder than that. Try it and if you get any problems ask another question.

Comment: How do I place the data inside of the table view?

Comment: Have you ever used the `UITableViewController`? This is very much the same, but you'll have to connect the delegate and datasource yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Scrolling Enabled on Table View ?
I don't think so you need to do anything. TableView will take care of it.